# Do slime chunks change version to version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am using a seed in 1.9 and programs like http://mineatlas.com and admidst are able to show me the biomes correctly when i load my world in version 1.8.9 (they haven't updated for 1.9).

My question is will slime chunks show correctly in the programs (1.8.9) if they are reading the world (1.9 loaded into the 1.8.9 programs)?

Comment: Considering that there are new stuff in 1.9, I'd expect bugs even if they work.

Answer (score 1):

Slime chunk generation should be the same for different versions of Minecraft. I haven't ever heard of the algorithm changing, and I don't think there would be much if any reason to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Slime chunks will display correctly if you input the seed in mine atlas and choose the version that the world was created in.
So if you made the world in 1.9 input 1.9
and if you made the world in 1.8.9 input 1.8.9 and so on

Hope this helps